# ASP.NET - ICollection becoming null after initializing and saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model with ICollection of type string:

```
public class Post{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> SampleList { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a new Post, I manually initialize SampleList like so:

```
Post post = new Post()
{
    Title = "John Doe",
    SampleList = new List<string>()
};
db.Posts.Add(post);
db.SaveChanges();
```

When I attempt to retrieve the same post from the details method on my controller and break, I can see that SamepleList is null. If I attempt to add a string to SampleList after that, I get a null reference exception.

Whats going on?

Comment: Post the code you use to retrieve the post.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's got much to do with ASP.NET, but has everything to do with whatever persistence technology you're using... what is that, EF? LINQ to SQL? You should be able to reproduce the problem in a console app that just saves and then loads the post.